# Unable to override @ImportResource for JunitTesting

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, configuration

I have a Spring Boot application that I would like to run some Junit tests on, using the @SpringBootTest annotation.

The issue I am having is my application normally uses an Ignite client node.  This does not work during testing as there is no Ignite server to connect to.  To solve this I am trying to provide a ignite config that will start as a server node and not look for any other nodes.

I have verified this will work by directly editing the existing config.  However I have been unable to get my class that manages my Ignite Client to take a specific test config rather than the default config.  The config is specified via an @ImportResource annotation to the path of  the xml file that contains the bean definition for the Ignite config.

I have tried adding `@ContextConfiguration(classes = IgniteCacheManager.class)` and `@TestPropertySource({"file:./src/test/resources/IgniteConfigTest.xml"})` to my test class without any luck.

Junit tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = IgniteCacheManager.class)
//@TestPropertySource({"file:./src/test/resources/IgniteConfigTest.xml"})
@ImportResource({"file:./src/test/resources/IgniteConfigTest.xml"})
public class JWTEndtoEndTest {

    @Test
    public void loginValidateAndLogOutUser() {
        //tests here
    }
}
```

User of Ignite config file"

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ImportResource( { "file:./config/IgniteConfig.xml" } )
public class IgniteCacheManager {
    
    @Autowired
    private IgniteConfiguration cfg;
    
    private Ignite igniteClient;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {           
            igniteClient = Ignition.start( cfg );

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Unable to connect to ignite  cache ", ex);
        }
    }
```